# Display Login screen and use Login details to Authenticate REST API in Azure Bot Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to integrate Azure BOT Framework inside my Android Mobile App. I thought of implementing a few API's inside BOT and give a response based on my queries. Since my APIs are secured, I need a token to access those API. So thought of prompting a Login dialog, inside the BOT window, and use those login credentials to fetch token and access the APIs. Please let me know if this is the right approach.

**NOTE:** I tried integrating the Rest API inside the BOT framework and I could able to do it successfully

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using login dialog is the recommended way to get access tokens in Azure bot service. You can config it on Azure portal => your bot/bot => Settings :
[image]

You can follow [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp) to config it.

Comment: In this case are we going to bring in ADAL?

Comment: @Rathish, in this case there is no need to import ADAL

Comment: @Rathish,how's going? has your issue got solved?